# Django: Updating request.user Instance

Tags: python, django

Here's my model

```
class Extra(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

My view is something like

```
def notifications(request):
    new = Extra.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    if new:
        Extra.objects.update(timestamp=timezone.now())
    else:
        Extra.objects.create(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())
```

I'm trying to save the Date-Time when a user has requested a specific page.

As you can see if data about the user is already present in database then i'm updating it when user is requesting the page else i'm creating a new instance for that user.

But this is not a good way to do so since it's updating the Entire database not just the specific instance related to the request.user as we can see in our view (4th line i guess).

So, how can I use the variable 'new' since it already holds the data (if present) & update just request.user instance in database?

Please helpme with this code. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call `update()` on your filtered QuerySet. You were almost there :)

```
new = Extra.objects.filter(user=request.user)

if new:
    # call update() on your QuerySet
    new.update(timestamp=timezone.now())

else:
    Extra.objects.create(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())
```

There's also a similar example in the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but maybe this might help you get to where you want to be.
In my application, I either insert a record with a 'created' timestamp or update an existing record with an 'updated' timestamp depending on whether the record already exists or not.  If I understand your problem correctly then it's not exactly the same but I think it's close enough to give you something to work with.

So what I do is I override the standard save method in my class. Because I do this for all records on all tables I have done this in my base class but you could just as easily do it just on the class you need.

Looking at your class I'd add something like the following:

```
class Extra(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User)
       timestamp = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           ''' Check to see if the record exists '''
           if not self.id:
           ''' If there is no id on the record it must be new so set the insert data '''
               self.user = request.user
               self.timestamp = timestamp.now()
           else:
               ''' If there is an id just update the timestamp '''
               self.timestamp = timestamp.now()
           return super(Extra, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Basically what this is looking to do is intercept the save call to the database, check to see if the record is new or not, process what you need to process and then use the return statement to send the record on its way to the database.

As I said, it may not solve your problem but hopefully it will help.

Best of luck.